"Mark Read" is not working in Messages on iPhone
After switching to iPhone/Messages from Android, Messages shows hundreds of unread messages and “Mark Read” does nothing:

Is there a way to filter to unread messages?

The tag is "messages", I've added it to your question ("iMessage" is the name of  Apple's own messaging protocol, the app is called "Messages").

@jaume thank you.

On iPhone, if you are in the "Messages" app, at the top left hand corner, click on the
< 

(left hand pointer), multiple times if needed, until you see the
< Filters

Once you click on the left hand pointing arrow next to the word filters, you should then see a list of :
All Messages
Known Senders
Unknown Senders
Unread Messages

So, there you can click upon 'Unread Messages' to ONLY show you un-read messages.
Additionally, once you are looking at your Unread Messages, you can also click upon the little circle with 3 dots in it to the right of the word Unread at the top, choose 'Select Messages', and then at the bottom left, click on :
Read All
That should result with ALL messages being marked as read.
